# Delphi XE - TObjectList Sorting

Tags: delphi, sorting, delphi-xe4

I have a list like this:

```
FMyScheduleList: TObjectList<TMySchedule>;
```

It has a property:

```
property ADate: TDate read FDate write FDate;
```

How can I sort the list by this property?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You must implement a Custom `IComparer` function passing this implementation to the [`Sort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Collections.TList.Sort) method of the [`System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Collections.TObjectList) class, you can do this using an anonymous with a method with the [`System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Generics.Defaults.TComparer) like so .

```
FMyScheduleList.Sort(TComparer<TMySchedule>.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TMySchedule): integer
      begin
         if L.ADate=R.ADate then
            Result:=0
         else if L.ADate< R.ADate then
            Result:=-1
         else
            Result:=1;
      end
));
```

As @Stefan suggest also you can use `CompareDate` function which is defined in the `System.DateUtils` unit.

```
FMyScheduleList.Sort(TComparer<TMySchedule>.Construct(
      function (const L, R: TMySchedule): integer
      begin
         Result := CompareDate(L.ADate, R.ADate);
      end
));
```

Comment: I would suggest using `DateUtils.CompareDate` which has 3 advantages: 1. you might not confuse the -1 and the 1 (happens to me all the time)  2. it actually just compares the date part and 3. shorter code in your delegate

Comment: On a side note, I found `CompareText`, but is there a ready function for `Integer` and `Boolean`? Currently I made my own `CompareInt`.

Comment: @JerryDodge It looks like there is one for all types of numbers called CompareValue. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Math.CompareValue